# PHP echo calculation with ordinal suffix

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to add the following text to a page in Wordpress: "Gina is now in her 16th (or sixteenth) year at the company," where 16th is a calculation based on her start year.

I know how to calculate her number of years at the company using PHP echo:

```
<?php echo date("Y")-1998 ?>
```

I also know that there are functions that can be used to attach a suffix to the number, such as:

```
<?php
    $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
    if (($number %100) >= 11 && ($number%100) <= 13)
        $abbreviation = $number. 'th';
    else
        $abbreviation = $number. $ends[$number % 10];
?>
```

What I don't know how to do is put these two things together and have them output properly on a Wordpress page. My knowledge of PHP is pretty basic so I'm hoping someone out here might have the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you said the answer yourself, just put that code together:

```
<?php
    $number = date("Y")-1998;
    $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');
    if (($number %100) >= 11 && ($number%100) <= 13) 
         $abbreviation = $number. 'th';
    else
         $abbreviation = $number. $ends[$number % 10];
    echo $abbreviation;
?>
```

Although I believe the base year would not be `date("Y")`, but some value fetched from wordpress about Gina.